# Java: catching a general exception, just in case?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Im new to Java here, so I was only guessing while working here.

I had some code

```
    try {
        sendMailWithAttachment(); 

    } catch (AddressException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        sendMailWithoutAttachment();

    } catch (MessagingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        sendMailWithoutAttachment();
    }
```

But the "catch" code was never executed, so I suspected there is another type of exception that Im not catching, and instead of guessing what it was, I decided to catch some "general" kind of exception, and I blindly tried this

```
    try {
        sendMailWithAttachment 

    } catch (AddressException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        sendMailWithoutAttachment();

    } catch (MessagingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        sendMailWithoutAttachment();
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sendMailWithoutAttachment();
    }
```

And then my catch code was suddenly ran.

What have I actually done here, and most importantly:

Can I always catch a general exception, just in case?

Comment: Use an IDE, it will automatically tell you what exception you haven't catched.

Comment: No, you should read javadoc and catch expected exceptions

Comment: @RohitJain With the exception of `Error`s (though are not exceptions...) and `RuntimeException`s

Comment: Im using Eclipse IDE, it generated the first two catch statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All exceptions subclass the `Exception` class. So, what you have done is said, "If an `AddressException` happens, handle it like this; if a `MessagingException` happens, handle it like this; for any other `Exception`, handle it like this."

In your case, all three `catch` blocks are identical, so you CAN just use your `catch (Exception e) { ... }` block, but this is considered poor coding. Typically, you should know which exceptions your code might throw and handle each of those exceptions appropriately.

Comment: so how do I know what exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Without knowing what code makes up your `sendMailWithAttachment()` method, I cannot say. However, the IDE will only generate `catch` blocks for `Exception`s that are intended. For things like `NullPointerException`s, these typically happen when you have a bug in your code. `e.printStackTrace()` should show lines in your console explaining what `Exception` has occurred, and what line of your code it happened on. This info will usually tell you the name of the Exception; you can look at Javadocs to figure out what the exceptions mean.

Comment: @JennyKowalski If `sendMailWithAttachment` is properly documented, it should tell you the exceptions it can throw under which circumstances. If not, you're probably stuck with catching `Exception`.

Comment: well its a custom method I have created. It also gets some data from two other methods that also throw exceptions. Should I handle those exceptions there in those methods, or in the last method that uses those methods?

Comment: @JennyKowalski: "_so how do I know what exceptions are thrown?_" `e.printStackTrace();` tells you...

Comment: @JennyKowalski, That is a stylistic and functional choice that you as the developer have to make, depending on your use case and needs. 

This link should help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: @jlordo Well, it only tells you what **is** thrown, not what **can be** thrown.

Comment: @JennyKowalski We can't tell you where to catch your exceptions, you'll have to decide where makes the most sense. But I imagine somewhere in your send function won't be a great idea, since you probably don't want to continue sending when you've gotten an exception, and putting a return or another throw in your catch statement has its uses, but generally isn't particularly great.

Comment: @Dukeling: exactly. As you can see in my comment, that was the question I was answering for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Catching a *general* `Exception` is always possible, though usually not a good practice.

Many times, a component cannot handle the exception, and there is really no point on catching it, and the 'upper levels' should handle it.

It also might create security risks (you don't want to display what went wrong in the program, you rather log it and send it to the dev team).

Notes:

1. Catching `Exception` will catch all *exceptions* which are extending `Exception`, but it won't catch all `Throwable`s (like `Error`).
2. In your code, what happens if the `catch` block itself throws an exception?  usually the exception handling should be very minimal, in your case, I'd try to verify before checking if sending mail with attachment is possible, and not only on the exception (if it can be done).
3. There is no point in catching multiple 'types' of exceptions and finally with `Exception` if the handling is the same, just catch `Exception` without the rest in this case.

Comment: so instead of printing stacktrace, I should log the errors?

Comment: @JennyKowalski It depends, but usually logging exceptions is better then displaying on screen, at least for production code.